# How to use an outside script within a Django Project?

Tags: python, django

Sorry for the wording on the question if it isn't clear.

I am rather new to Django but not too new to Python. I have a Model in my Django Project, which keeps track of trailer locations. I then need to use another script to update this data. However, when running this script, the Dict that is suppose to be returned is not getting returned properly.

```
class TrailerLocation(models.Model):
    trailer = models.OneToOneField(Trailer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    locationCity = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    locationState = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    locationCountry = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    locationStatus = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return self.trailer

    def createLocation(self, trailer):
        trailerLocation = TrailerLocation(trailer=trailer)
        trailerLocation.save()

    def getLocations(self):
        locDataDict = trailerLocations.run()
        print(locDataDict)
        for key in locDataDict.keys():
            datalist = locDataDict[key]
            self.updateLocation(key, datalist)
```

Comment: where is the script? and what do you mean by `the Dict that is suppose to be returned is not getting returned properly.`

Comment: The question is completely unclear, but if you want to have `./manage.py my_command --my-opt=foo ...`  for use in a shell script, writing management commands is documented: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: It looks like `trailerLocations.run()` is supposed to be your "outside script"? That's just calling a function, but we have no idea what `trailerLocations.run()` _does_. If you have a problem with that function (e.g. if it "is not returning properly") we need more information about _that_. Please [edit] and show us a [mre] version of that function, plus add clarity about the specific problem. "Not getting returned properly" is not at all clear. Please read [ask].